# Запрос на данные с поля при id =...

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Как изменить запрос?

В общем есть 2 таблицы massage и datacenter.

В datacenter поля id, name, surname...

В massage text, id_finish, id_start, avatar

Смысл этого запроса такой  я достаю имя и фамилию, а они находятся в другой таблице.Под именем(datacenter). А id_finish(id человека которому отправляется сообщения) это внешний ключ к полю id таблицы datacenter.

Проблема в том, что путь к аватару(данные с поля avatar), дастаются при id_start = '$id'
Но мне надо , что-бы  данные с поля  avatar,  брались при другом условии id_finish = '$id'
 **Короче смысл таков что для поля avatar мне надо id_finish= '$id' , а для остальных полей id_start = '$id'**

```
 $a = mysql_query("SELECT datacenter.id, text, avatar, id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname 
      FROM massage massage join datacenter datacenter on datacenter.id = massage.id_finish 
      WHERE id_start = '$id'");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
 {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: AlexWindHope спасай?

Comment: Добавьте структуру и словесное описание таблиц... ИМХО: Сложно судить по кривому запросу

Comment: Что означает поле avatar?? как-то в нём смысла не видно ( почему оно хранится в massage а не datacenter ???)

Comment: @Zow, используйте заголовки тем по назначению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен что смог прочитать мысли, тем не менее попробуй так, если не то - тогда действительно прийдется расписать структуру таблиц и что именно ты хочешь от запроса.

```
 SELECT datacenter.id, text, avatar, id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname
      FROM massage JOIN datacenter
          ON datacenter.id = massage.id_finish
                WHERE  message.id_finish= '$id'
```

Т.е., по сути, практически тот-же запрос только без ошибок :)

---

**UPD**

Как вариант как-то так:

```
SELECT datacenter.id, text, (
            SELECT avatar FROM message WHERE `id_finish`= $id
      ) AS finishAvatar,
      id_finish, datacenter.name, datacenter.surname
           FROM massage JOIN datacenter
          ON datacenter.id = massage.id_finish
                WHERE  message.id_start= '$id'
```

Теперь, если запрос корректен и выборка прошла успешно, поидее к `avatar'у` выбранному по id_finish можно обратится как-то так: (остальные же поля выбираются по id_start)

```
  $res = mysql_query('тут сам запрос');
  while($row = mysql_feth_assoc($res)) {
       echo $row['finishAvatar'];
  }
```

Если не работает - ты помнишь, `or die(mysql_error())` и ошибку в студию

Comment: не то, ты поменял id_start на id_finish, так ты мне исаортил запросы к другим полям.
Короче смысл таков что для поля avatar мне надо  id_finish= '$id'
, а для остальных полей  id_start = '$id'

Comment: Типа, мне надо, через два внешних ключей обратится к одной таблице, в одном запросе.

Comment: ну если это не то что тебе нужно тогда я не могу понять что тебе нужно :)

Comment: я завтра посмотрю) сень уже не смогу)
завтра вечером буиш в ВК? гдето в часов 5, 6?

Comment: все работает спс